# Animating Top and Bottom Position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

i'm trying to animate with jQuery. 
http://jsfiddle.net/g8mQu/

```
 $('#down').on("click", function() {
    $('#inner').animate({ "top": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
 });
```

That's my code pretty much and it works in this demo, but i'm trying to implement this into a Bootstrap framework site. The css is the same though, the wrapper is a container and the scrollable div is a col-xs div.
This should work fine but whenever I click a button it doesn't add 50 to the position but sets the position to 50 / -50 even though i'm using the "+=50" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
$('#down').on("click", function() {
    var $inner = $('#inner');
    $inner.animate({ "top": $inner.css("top") - 50 }, "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything then. console.log($inner.css("top")-50); gives me NaN, console.log($inner.css("top")-50px); gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

Comment: Nvm it was the jQuery Version... I feel kind of dumb now. Thanks for your time anyway